# Would you recommend Python or NodeJS for creating real-time web service?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, django, socket.io

I want to create a web application, which is **real-time** in nature (**dashboard**). I am seeking suggestions regarding what stack should I choose for the project in order to maintain it in long run, considering the time and complexity of maintaining the project, maintaining **API**.

Here are some of my requirements:

- Realtime updates on dashboard about recent events.
- Proper API for the service.
- Focus on the problem, rather than handling configurations and tweaking.

**The problem** : I am confused about my choices, and find it hard to take decision that would help me in long run.

Here are some things I have figured out after research:

- Both Python and NodeJS have frameworks (SocketIO, Greenlets, Twisted, etc.) for websockets. However, the support for asynchronous processing is better in JavaScript.
- Callback hell may suck. In fact, you cannot expect the return value of a function for all calls are asynchronous (there are Promises). However, one has to follow decent programming practices.
- Python gives you more control over the code and is easier to maintain.
- Javascript for me has been notorious for surprises, breaking things after few updates. The community is moving fast, but that may be too fast for enterprise level applications. Still, there are examples of big enterprises like PayPal, Google appreciating that.
- Javascript is becoming the new cool, so I am more likely to find maintainers for my project or more recruits in future.
- Stuff like creating APIs is easier in JavaScript using Express as compared to Django/Flask.
- A node project usually has a hell lot of modules (was watching some projects on Github), like BodyParser, Meteor, Webpack. I don't know them, but feels like too much to work with.
- It is relatively hard to shit in Python, and the community is more mature and stable. Contrary to it, Node has awful lot of modules for simple tasks, most of them created by sub-standard programmers just because they are easier to make. (no offense to you, you are not one of them :P)
- There are solutions like Firebase, but I want to refrain from using that for that causes heavy dependency on proprietary tools in the long run. Suggestions are welcome.

**Why am I asking?**

You are probably more experienced than me in dealing with such applications in daily life.

PS: I have decent experience in both JavaScript and Python (more efficient in Python). But please don't consider language as a barrier. I want a solution so that even if I get more members on my team, they should be comfortable with the codebase.

**Edit:** Stack Exchange does not permit opinion based questions. This should not be one. I intend to have a logical argument from someone choosing a particular solution among many available. Your expertise over a domain is required before giving a review to rather than opinion. Please refrain from putting this on hold.

Comment: Both of them can do this.Different programmers prefer different prgramming language.So why don't you choose one you're good at?

Comment: Please consider before putting the question hold. I don't intend to seek opinions, but facts, expertise, and references for preference of one stack over another. You can instead downvote opinionated answers instead of the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is personal preference as much as anything else. My personal preferance would definentally be NodeJS. The reasons are:

- Frameworks like Socket.io are amazing and very easy to implement via npm.
- Node moves fast, but I have never had trouble with it breaking on me.
- Like you said creating APIs in JS is easier.
- NPM is amazing! the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/) are **super** helpful.

At the end of the day it is your call. That being said I would hands-down go with nodeJS any day.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look to **rethinkdb**.

It would be very useful for your scenario. Choose whichever language you like more. I would advise to choose **Node.js** - you would have more people contributing to your project.

[*Rethinkdb* resources](https://rethinkdb.com/)